# wrong month in date parsing

Tags: java, date

I have  a string in the following format.

```
07/06/2011 5:06
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm
```

am using following code

```
DateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
date = (Date)dateFormater.parse(dateTimeStr);


but for input = 03/05/2011 9:45
i get op = Wed Jan 05 09:45:00 IST 2011
```

Why so?I gave month as march but i am getting jan as month

Whats the issue with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the format to MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm 
ref: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

Months use capital `M` - `MM/dd/yyyy` - [check the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

You're aware that `month` is an uppercase `M`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm
mm stands for minute in hour. But you need MM which stands for Month in year.